# Image Processing -how can i extract a desired segment from a frame?

Tags: image-processing

how can i extract a desired segment from a frame? like I capture a video of a moving car from the front or the rear side.So from different set of frames i want to extract only that segment of the image having Car no.

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Please read: http://stackoverflow.com/help/asking
People won't be able to give you useful help without more details.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I dont know which language you are using, but you might want to take a look at 
[OpenCV](http://opencv.org/), it has a pretty nice toolbox for image-manipulation and capturing.

If you want to extract Number Plates from the Videostream, I reccomend you to look at this [tutorial](http://visakh017.blogspot.de/2014/05/license-plate-detection-and.html)

Comment: I am using  C++ in visual studio with OpenCv

Comment: Car no. means Numberplate?